# URL Rewrite Management problem with rewrites

Tags: url-rewrite

Scenario Magento 1.9.1.0

We have3 stores for 3 languages
For URL SEO language

1. We go to **URL Rewrite Management**
2. We Locate Request Path with System Type selection.
3. We Modify the request path to language store with this, System, Store Language, ID Path original path, request path how to url on language desire, and target path original. Redirect No.

Well, we test the new URL such https://dulcissimus.fr/ayurveda-homme-tisane-organique-sprecial-pour-les-hommes-saveur-de-gingembre.html and it works well for somedays.

After some days (on latest day there're any upgrades of Magento core modules) on **URL Rewrite Management** there aren't a Type System URL Rewrite. Instead, Magento show a **Custom** url.

This custom URL it's create by???? we dont know what it is. For us it's a ghost or the sistem. We don't know how magento can change an URL rewrite system to custom rewrite.
We do apreciate help

[image: URL Rewrite Management after creation]

[image: URL Rewrite wrong after several days or possible update??]

Edited: 17h55 GMT+1 
We add further information that can maybe help to better resolve or understand the problem:
we have made a series of tests so as to analyze the issue and we find out that the modified URL works fine till we make change in the url key (default Store View). At this time the modified url changed the to Custom and not system. but we are not sure if is the origen of the problem because we did not made changes allover the product and still all the product in the french view have changed the URl  status from system to custom.

Regards

Comment: do you have any 3rd party extension?

Comment: I've a lot of extensiones of 3rd party. For UrlTranslate only one, but deactivate.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Catalog URL system is creating an URL for the product and the rewrite being created by you is not working because of that.

Do this:
1. remove the custom rewrite you created manually.
2. go to product and create the rewrite from there. This means adding as URL key the string you want to use. For example, if you want www.domain.com/magento-2 put only magento-2 in the URL key field.

Comment: help me @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/219953/57334

Answer (score 0):

Although magento 1 is obsolete, but I encountered this also ... one fix would be to look in the table 
**catalog_category_entity_varchar** , filter by entity_id (=category_id) and delete all rows which have the store_id = 1 (or different from 0).

After this every time you will change the url_key of the category the url_rewrite will update the main store url also.

Comment: Question is asked 4 years, 11 months ago. Good chance

Comment: Its now even more years and I still have the same issue. Its never to late to add possible solutions. Thanks Bogdan!